# javascript and jquery order of execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write some code using Javascript/ jQuery/ Google Maps API.

However, the order of execution in my script is a bit weird.

```
var flats=[];
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.062, 19.937),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);

  /* Puling flats data using my API */
  $.getJSON("http://ks3353689.kimsufi.com:5000/v1/closest_pointlng=19.937&lat=50.062",parseFlat);
  function parseFlats(data){
    /* I put flats data in format usable by Google maps API */
    $.each(data, function(i, item){
      flat = [];
      flat.push('flat_name');
      flat.push(parseFloat(item.latitude));
      flat.push(parseFloat(item.longitude));
      // z-index to display flats on map
      flat.push(i+1);
      flats.push(flat);
    });
    console.log("I'm inside the function");
  }
  console.log("activating markers");
  setMarkers(map, flats);
}
```

I thought that jQuery API call will be executed before setMarkers function, but when I look into firebug, the order is different:

```
activating markers
I'm inside the function
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I make sure jQuery part is executed before setMarkers function?

Comment: If you want a *defined* order, just put `setMarkers()` at the end of your callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the asynchronous nature of $.getJSON. If you need to call setMarkers(map, flats) only after parseFlats, call it inside parseFlats

```
$.getJSON("http://ks3353689.kimsufi.com:5000/v1/closest_pointlng=19.937&lat=50.062",parseFlat);
function parseFlats(data){
  /* I put flats data in format usable by Google maps API */
  $.each(data, function(i, item){
    flat = [];
    flat.push('flat_name');
    flat.push(parseFloat(item.latitude));
    flat.push(parseFloat(item.longitude));
    // z-index to display flats on map
    flat.push(i+1);
    flats.push(flat);
  });
  console.log("I'm inside the function");
  console.log("activating markers");
  setMarkers(map, flats);      
}
```

The other possibility is to use $.ajax with asyn property set to false (but I won't recommend it, as the browser blocks until the server answer is received)

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: 'http://ks3353689.kimsufi.com:5000/v1/closest_pointlng=19.937&lat=50.062',
  success: parseFlat,
  async:false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The precise order of execution is:

1. Assign variable `mapOptions`
2. Assign variable `map`
3. Call `$.getJSON`, which sends an AJAX request and registers the function to be called when the reply is received.
4. Log `activating markers`
5. Call `setMarkers()`.
6. Return from the `initialize()` function to the browser's event loop.
7. When the AJAX response is received, call `parseFlats()`, which logs `I'm inside the function`.

Remember, the first A in AJAX stands for *asynchronous*.

Answer (score 0):

Move `setMarkers` inside at the of `parseFlats` and you get the order you want.